# System.Drawing.Color in console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

Simple question from .NET beginner. 
How to work with colors in console application? VS do not let me declarate System.Drawing.Color namespace. I need to assign color for one method in console application.

Regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All you need to do is add a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`. This isn't included by default in a console app, but you can add it without any issues.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually very simple, for example:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Yellow");
```